# I'm in trouble with creating new object in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm having a trouble with it.
I've tried to create new object without (*), so `Animal a1;` but it didn't work.
So now I'm using `Animal* a1;`, and it works, but the problem is that it says it has to be initialised.
I made a default constructor, so doesn't it mean that it initialises automatically or should I initialise it again?
These are my code:

### `Animal.cpp`:

```
#include "Animal.h"

using namespace std;

Animal::Animal(int newid, double newweight, int yy, int mm, int dd, double newaccDose, char newsex)
{
    id = newid;
    weight = newweight;
    yy = yy;
    mm = mm;
    dd = dd;
    dose = newaccDose;
    sex = newsex;
}

Animal::Animal()
{
    id = 0;
    weight = 0;
    yy = 0;
    mm = 0;
    dd = 0;
    dose = 0;
    sex = ' ';
}

Animal::~Animal(){}

double Animal::getDaysDifference(){
    jdate dateOfBirth(dd,mm,yy);
    jdate now;
    double diff = now-dateOfBirth;
    return diff;
}

void Animal::addAnimal(){
    int select=0;

    while(select==1 || select==2){
        cout << "1.  Cattle    2.  Sheep" << endl;
        cout << "Select a type of animal: ";
        cin >> select;
        cout << "Invalid number please try again" << endl;  
    }

}
```

### `Animal.h`

```
#ifndef ANI_H
#define ANI_H
#include <vector>
#include "Treatment.h"
#include "jdate.h"

class Animal{
protected:
    int id;
    double weight;
    int yy;
    int mm;
    int dd;
    double dose;
    char sex;
    //Treatment treatArray[];
public:
    Animal();
    Animal(int newid, double newweight, int yy, int mm, int dd, double newdose, char newsex);
    ~Animal();
    virtual double calcDose() = 0;
    void addAnimal();
    void questions(); // ask questions like id,weight, and so on
    double getDaysDifference();
};
#endif
```

### `DrugAdmin.cpp`

```
//Main function
#include <iostream>
#include "Animal.h"
#include "Cattle.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Animal* a1;

    a1->addAnimal();
}
```

I just did it to check if the `addAnimal()` function is working but apparently it's not.
Can you please give me a piece of advice?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare

```
Animal* a1;
```

`a1` doesn't point to anything: it's an uninitialised variable, which has an undefined value. Calling a method on it has undefined behaviour. If you have a default constructor, you can create a default-constructed local `Animal` like so:

```
Animal a1;
```

This `Animal` will exist till the end of the scope in which it's defined. If you need an `Animal` that should live beyond the end of a function, you can allocate it dynamically with `new`, which gives you an `Animal*` (pointer to `Animal`) that you must later `delete`:

```
Animal* make_animal() {
    return new Animal();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Animal* a1 = make_animal();
    delete a1;
}
```

You should avoid using `new` and `delete` unless it's really necessary, of course. There are loads of good answers here on StackOverflow that cover similar ground. Search for them.

Comment: I tried Animal a1; before but it says
object of abstract class type "Animal" is not allowed:
How come my Animal class is abstract class??

Comment: @jcarlos: An abstract class is one which has one or more `virtual` functions that are declared pure virtual with `= 0`, or which inherits from one or more abstract classes and does not provide implementations for all of the pure virtual functions it inherits.

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
while(select==1 || select==2){
```

in `addAnimal()` should be:

```
while ((select != 1) && (select !=2)) {
```

The way you currently have it, it will never *enter* the loop because `select` is initialised to 0, which is neither 1 nor 2. That's because it means "run this loop while the value is either 1 or 2". The latter means "run this loop while it's neither 1 nor 2".

Hence, if by some bizarre sunspot--or-thermonuclear-explosion-induced error it *did* enter that loop, it would stay in there until you entered an *invalid* value rather than a valid one.

You also want to examine the line:

```
cout << "Invalid number please try again" << endl;
```

since it will output that string even if you enter a valid value (easiest solution is probably to wrap an `if` around it).

Comment: Thanks now I just removed while loop, and used if instead

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually calling the default construct nor are you creating Animal object when you say Animal* a1 it just allocates enough space for a pointer.